# Comparing two list, returning the results to display

Tags: python

I am trying to create compare two lists of MD5hashes. I need to identify what hashes compare and return the hashes that compare. I am not having much luck in doing so any help would be amazing.

This is what I have at the minute:

```
BadHashes = []
for element in filesavedin:
    if element in hasheddic:
        BadHashes.append(element)
        print BadHashes
return BadHashes
```

Comment: put your items in `set`s and use `intersection`

Comment: I am rather new to python and not to sure how to use sets. how would I structure it ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation on sets: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

Codewise:

```
from set import Set

set1 = Set([1,1,2,3])
set2 = Set([2,2,3,4])

intersecting = set1.intersection(set2)
```

Should give you `intersecting = Set([2,3])`. You can convert this back to a list object by using `list(intersecting)` although most list operators also work on sets.

Comment: The MD5 hashes will match but the text wont, will that cause an error?
['706a5076efba4babff1a1a22d394f9c7:icon_clown.gif', 'f6bea6e63a1d311e32a759d6f4859ace:sleeper.jpg', 'e4e7c3451a35944ca8697f9f2ac037f1:StarWarsReview.docx',  '6bbaa34b19edd6c6fa06cccf29b33125:nothingtoseehere.docx', 

['9d377b10ce778c4938b3c7e2c63a229a:contraband_file1.jpg', '6bbaa34b19edd6c6fa06cccf29b33125:contraband_file2.jpg', 'e4e7c3451a35944ca8697f9f2ac037f1:contraband_file3.jpg', '1d6d9c72e3476d336e657b50a77aee05:contraband_file4.gif']

Comment: I suggest then that you pre-process your lists to isolate just the md5 hashes. Use a list comprehension e.g. `proc_list = [x.split(":")[0] for x in hash_list]`, then run the intersection on those so you will only compare the md5 hashes.

Comment: If I then wanted to add the file e.g (StarWarsReview.docx) with the MD5 hash how would you go about that?

Comment: I would create a dict storing the md5 hashes as keys and the filenames as values (again from the list comprehension) - something like: `file_map = {x.split(":")[0], x.split(":")[1] for x in hash_list]`, and then look up the intersected set on the keys once you had done the set intersection, e.g. `final_list = [md5 + ":" + file_map[md5] for md5 in intersecting]`. Hope this helps.